# Geodesics on $S^2$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Correct description of this problem is here: [Geodesics on $S^2$ with specific Riemannian metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986510/geodesics-on-s2-with-specific-riemannian-metric)

I was asked to show the following:

> Given a Riemannian metric on $S^2$, let $x \in S^2$ be the north pole, and let $V(\theta) \in T_xS^2$ be unit tangent vectors at $x$. Then there exists a constant $t > 0$ such that $\exp_x(tV(\theta))$ is the south pole for all $\theta$.

The conclusion in this statement is really not intuitive for me, and I am not sure how to approach this problem. Could someone give a hint on this?

Comment: Presumably the question concerns the _round_ metric on the sphere (for which the conclusion is true), not an _arbitrary_ metric (for which the conclusion is false).

Comment: I was not provided with this condition. But could you explain more about it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: What are the geodesics of a round unit sphere?

Start at a point $x$ of a round unit $2$-sphere and walk at unit speed. How long does it take to reach the antipode $-x$?

---

By contrast, consider an arbitrary metric on a $2$-sphere. As a physical analogy, imagine the surface of a [squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita) or a [gourd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourd), where the center of the stem end is the north pole and the south pole is the center of the blossom end. It's not obvious that a geodesic starting at the north pole ever *reaches* the south pole. Certainly, different geodesics between the poles have different lengths.

Comment: I do understand what you said here. I guess I did not state the problem correctly. The assumption on the Riemannian metric is that all the geodesics originating from the north pole go through the same point (maybe call it the south pole), and the conclusion would be that all these geodesics have the same length.

Comment: Ah, I see. The "usual site culture" would be to post a separate question, possibly linking back to this one, or linking forward from this one to the revised statement. (It would be helpful if, in the new question, you could say something about "available technology", e.g., whether you know about Jacobi fields or the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.) If you revise this question, however, I'll delete this answer and my comment.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have posted another question describing what I have for the problem at the moment. I think I am mostly there, but missing a little detail. It would be great if you could help with that.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition.** Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p, q\in M$ aretwo points. The pair $(p,q)$ is called a *[wiedersein pair](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WiedersehenPair.html)* if every geodesic through $p$ also passes through $q$.

Given your comments to Andrew Hwang's answer, your precise question is the following:

Assuming that the north pole - the south pole pair $(p,q)$ in $S^2$ is a wiedersein pair, show that all simple geodesic arcs from $p$ to $q$ have the same length.

To prove this, consider the 1-parameter family of geodesics (parameterized by arclength) $\gamma_\theta(t)$ with $\gamma_\theta(0)=p$, $\gamma_\theta'(0)=V(\theta)$ as in your question. Let $L(\theta)$ denote the least value of $t$ such that $\gamma_\theta(L(\theta))=q$. Then $L(\theta)$ is the length of $\gamma_\theta|[0,L(\theta)]$. Recall that every geodesic  between two points $p, q$ (in any Riemannian manifold) is a critical point of the length function restricted to the space of all smooth curves connecting $p$ and $q$. Therefore, the derivative $L'(\theta)$ is identically zero. Hence, since the circle is connected, $L$ is constant. qed