# Geodesics on $S^2$ with specific Riemannian metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

This is a revision of the statement in the question [Geodesics on $S^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977863/geodesics-on-s2)

> Suppose a Riemannian metric on $S^2$ satisfies the condition that there exist points $N,S \in S^2$ such that all geodesics originating from $N$ pass through $S$. Then the arc-lengths of all these geodesics are the same, assuming each geodesic connects $N$ to $S$ and does not pass through $S$ in the middle.

I started with picking a $v_0 \in T_NS^2$ such that $\exp_N(v_0) = S$, and let $\gamma_0 \colon [0,1] \to S^2$ be defined by $\gamma_0(t) = \exp_N(tv_0)$.

Then let $v \colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to T_nS^2$ be a smooth map such that $v(0) = v(0)$, and $\exp_N(v(u)) = S$.

Now we have a one-parameter family of geodesics $\gamma_u(t) = \exp_N(tv(u))$. 
If we define $\alpha \colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times [0,1] \to S^2$ by $\alpha(u,t) = \gamma_u(t) = \exp_N(tv(u))$, we get a variation of $\gamma_0$ through geodesics, and this variation fixes endpoints $N$ and $S$. 
So we have the following facts:

(1) $\displaystyle v(u) = \frac{d}{dt} \gamma_u(0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \Big|_{t=0}$

(2) $\displaystyle \frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) = 0$

(3) $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,0) = 0$, and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,1) = 0$.

If we can show that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{du} \|v(u)\| = 0$, we can use a compactness argument on $S^1$ to say that the arc-length of $\gamma_u$ does not depend on $u$.

My trouble is in the following argument:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{du} \langle v(u),v(u) \rangle 
> &= \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \Big|_{t=0} 
> = 2 \langle \frac{D}{\partial u} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t)\rangle\Big|_{t=0} \\
> &= 2 \langle \frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t)\rangle\Big|_{t=0} \\
> &= 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \Big|_{t=0} - 2 \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \Big|_{t=0} \\
> &= 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \Big|_{t=0} 
> \end{align*}

I am not sure how to conclude that the expression evaluates to be zero. But I assume I need to make use of fact (3) afterwards, since I have not used it anywhere in my argument. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @HKLee How do I conclude the last sequence of expressions give zero?

Comment: In assumption all geodesics from $N$ to $S$ has same length In your setting $|v(u)|$ is constant so that automatically it is $0$ without calculation

Comment: @HKLee That is not my assumption. I am trying to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.

To show that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \Big|_{t=0} = 0$, I only need to show that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle$ is constant in $t$, i.e., $\displaystyle \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle$ is linear in $t$, and conclude that it must be $0$ by fact (3).

Now,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle
=& \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle \frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \\
=& \langle \frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \\
=& \langle \frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{D}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t), \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \\
=& \langle \frac{D}{\partial u}\frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) + R(\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial t})\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \alpha(u,t) \rangle \\
=& \langle R(\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial t})\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t} \rangle = 0
\end{align*}